# A simple matter of relations (What am I?)

Tags: graph-theory, number-property

Don't overthink it,

just a little fun.

Relations are part of graphs,

of which I am one.

What is my relation?

[image]

Hint 1

> Nodes were chosen at random, thus this is a random subgraph (but not an *induced* subgraph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation just appears to be

> numbers that are anagrams, with the first digit kept in place?